# `max-width` and `min-width` shorthands

Tags: css

Is there a shorthand for this properites?

For example, right now I do:

```css
.main-exchange-container--title {
  min-width: 288px;
  max-width: 900px;;
}
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```css
.main-exchange-container--title {
  widths: 288px  900px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No but it can be done like below:

```css
.main-exchange-container--title {
  /*
  min-width: 288px;
  max-width: 900px;
  */
  width:clamp(288px,100%,900px);
  
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-exchange-container--title"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific shorthand, but in vanilla CSS you could move it to its own class if reused a lot, eg.

```css
._width-primary {
  min-width: 288px;
  max-width:900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-exchange-container--title _width-primary">
</div>
```

---

Or, If you have 'framework' libraries, they may have classes to help simplify this (eg. [bootstrap's grids/columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/))

```html
<div class="main-exchange-container--title col-12">
</div>
```

(it'll behave a little different to your rules though, so youd need to find the closest equivalent)

---

Or, If you have a pre-processor like [LESS](https://lesscss.org/#mixins) or [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin), it probably has a feature like mixins/includes to reuse certain rules without needing to export extra classes and add it to your HTML.

Example in LESS:

```
._width-primary() {
  min-width: 288px;
  max-width: 900px;
}
.main-exchange-container--title {
  ._width-primary()
}
```

in Sass (SCSS):

```
@mixin _width-primary {
  min-width: 288px;
  max-width: 900px;
}
.main-exchange-container--title {
  @include _width-primary;
}
```

both of the above will output this CSS:

```css
.main-exchange-container--title {
     min-width: 288px;
     max-width: 900px;
}
```